# how to view flexbox pop-up shown in Chrome dev tool in Firefox as well?

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

I find Chrome dev tool's feature super useful, where you can bring up pop-up by clicking on flex icon and play around.

Just for this feature I need to shift to Chrome otherwise FF is best to debug during development.

Any idea if this can be achievable in FF as well ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not available in the Firefox DevTools yet (as of Firefox 100.0).

There is an [enhancement request](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1492055) asking to enable an "alignment inspector", which doesn't seem to be implemented at the moment.

Comment: danke schön für detailed clarification :)